GitHub: How to show contributors?
Not sure this is the right platform, but I ask anyway.
I have a github-repo where several people have made a PR which I have accepted.
Now I want those people to appear as "contributors". Like in https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js and so on. How do I do that?

What do you mean by "made a PR"? Did they make commits?

@Schwern, made a Pull Request, merged / accepted, and I assumed the contributors then would appear automatically - as I myself appear when i contribute to other projects the same way - to the left bottom, under "Contributors" - but they dont.

@Schwern, the repo in question -> https://github.com/davidkonrad/toUnicodeVariant you can see, I guess, that there have been two pull requests. I would like those contributors to be shown as contributors. I thought that happened automagically ...

The problem is the commits in the PR do not appear to be associated with their Github accounts. This can happen if their Git is configured to use an email address different from those associated with their Github account. You can see their email address in git log.
For example, this commit by "Sebastian Lagemann"

Note there is no Github avatar next to their name, and it is not a link to a Github account.
They will have to add the email addresses they use to make their commits to their accounts if they wish to be counted as a contributor. You could add a reply to their PRs to let them know.
See Troubleshooting contributors.

Thanks a lot! That makes sense, could not find the setting or option I thought I have missed ...
